# The most efficient notification system for a web application

Tags: node.js, websocket, notifications, xmpp

I have `VPS` hosting for a business application. It has XMPP based chat with Openfire which is working fine.
I want a real time notification system as well in our system.

- I have these options
- Ajax Long Poll
- PHP websockets
- Node.js
- Using XMPP(Not sure if applicable)

Among all the above. Which one would be the quickest one?

Comment: why should this question be closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMPP over websocket would be a good fit as it simply builds on your existing infrastructure.